# Pycharm/python no limpia consola y solo imprime simbolo Form Feed (FF)

Tags: python, consola, pycharm

Al querer usar mi codigo no solo no limpia la consola, sino que tambien imprime un simbolo que supongo es el Form Feed(FF), por lo que investigué. Cabe destacar que este mismo codigo sí me funciona en Visual Studio Code:

```
import os
import platform


def LimpiarConsola():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


print("hola mundo")
a = input("Enter para limpiar consola")
LimpiarConsola()
```